# Remove generated input areas with mouseover

Tags: javascript, input

This is my code:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  
  let fklas = document.createElement("input"); 
  fklas.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  
  let randomX = 10
  let randomY = 10
  
  fklas.style.top= randomX + "%"
  fklas.style.left= randomY + "%"
  document.body.append(fklas);
 },100)
  
  
function mouseOver() {
 console.log(this.id);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
}
```

I want to remove input areas with mouseover. Should be like a game. My remove function does not work. Can someone fix that please?

Love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append it to every generated element.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  let fklas = document.createElement("input");
  fklas.setAttribute('type', 'text');

  let randomX = 10
  let randomY = 10

  fklas.style.top = randomX + "%"
  fklas.style.left = randomY + "%"
  fklas.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver) // <-----
  document.body.append(fklas);
}, 100)


function mouseOver() {
  console.log(this.id);
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}

// <-- there are no element generated at this point so your for loop is effectively no-op
```

---

*I omit the style part because it's different question.